# Testing a controller action by an authorized user when using Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, pundit

How do you test a controller action (eg. show) for an authorized user when the app uses Pundit for authorization.

Info:

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def show
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    authorize @plan
  end
  .
  .
end

class PlanPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def show?
    record.users.include? user
     end

    end

require 'test_helper'

class PlansControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

test 'When user is authorized should get show' do
    @plan = @planone
    sign_in @userdom
    # what do I put here?
    get :show, id: @plan
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Show plan | Plennel"
  end
end
```

I already test the plan_policy in plan_policy_test.rb.
Some options I have tried are:

Setting authorize to true in the controller test.

Skipping authorize in the controller test.

Solutions I have found are either using [RSpec](http://thunderboltlabs.com/blog/2013/03/27/testing-pundit-policies-with-rspec/) (while I use Minitest with fixtures) or Mocha or go into detail with regard to testing Pundit policies but don't explain testing controller actions that require an authorized user.

I am looking for a simple way to skip (or fake) authorization in tests without the use of gems or other test suites than Minitest. I have been trying to get my head around this for for two days now so help would be greatly appreciated!

btw: I still have a lot to learn with regard to Rails development so apologies if I'm asking the wrong questions or if I'm giving the wrong info.

Comment: Hey buddy, I think I asked a similar question and answered it myself here using Mini Test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690056/rails-pundit-mini-test-assert-response-punditnotauthorizederror/40690092#40690092

Answer (score 1):

`authorize` calls `show?` method in `PlanPolicy` beneath the hood. You just need to stub that to return true.

To do it in plain Ruby, you'd put something like this at the start of your spec.

```
class PlanPolicy
  def show? ; true ; end
end
```

I'm not familiar with Minitest, but it should support stubbing too.

Comment: For some reason I get an unknown method error when I try the above. Not being able to find a solution I have installed the Mocha gem and use `policy = stub(create?: true); PlanPolicy.stubs(:new).returns(policy)` Needing a gem just to be able to stub Pundit policies is not my first pick but for now it'll have to do.