# Rails Pundit mini test assert_response Pundit::NotAuthorizedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, pundit

I am using Rails 5 API, Pundit and all is going well. I am trying to test this specific case where if you're not the resource owner, you should not be able to view that user's info.

So I got a few user fixture sample data, Sarah and Jim are two of them.

I got this test case here:

```
test "user show - cannot show other user's info" do
  get user_path(@sarah), headers: user_authenticated_header(@jim)
  assert_raises(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError)
end
```

I ran my test, all the other ones passed, except this one which says:

```
Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_user_show_-_cannot_show_other_user's_info:
Pundit::NotAuthorizedError: not allowed to show?
```

Am I writing the assert_raise exception correctly? Why is my test not passing? It seems like once the error is raised, the next line in my test is not ran anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate it when I keep answering my own questions...far out :(

After more searching, it turns out it's like this:

```
test "user show - cannot show other user's info" do
  assert_raises(Pundit::NotAuthorizedError) {
    get user_path(@sarah), headers: user_authenticated_header(@jim)
  }
end
```

I found the answer after finding this:

http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_raise

assert_raises takes an error type, in my case `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError` and a block of code to assert the error will be raised for.

In other words:

```
assert_raises(ExceptionType) {
  // my code to execute that will cause the error to happen
}
```

My other searches usually turns up RSpec testing syntax. Leaving this answer here for future Rails developers using Mini Test like me :D